# Reuse default AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to use it-the AccountController class that is created by default when I create an MVC web project using VS10. I would to add an action link next to Home so that I can log in or register a new user ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this, Home View

```
@Html.ActionLink("yourLinkText", "YourLogOnAction", "YourAccountController")


@Html.ActionLink("yourLinkText", "YourRegisterAction", "YourAccountController")
```